# Receive object htmlinputelement instead of class

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanna try import a json file an display it in html but my object 'selection' is always converted in object HTMLInputElement instead of my class.

this is the json

```
[
{
    "id":0,
    "name":"France",
    "acronym":"FR",
},
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Italy",
    "acronym":"IT",
},
{
    "id":2,
    "name":"Spain",
    "acronym":"SP",
}]
```

this is the class

```
export class Country {
id!:number
name!:string
acronym!:string

constructor(id:number, name:string, acronym:string) {
    this.acronym = acronym
    this.name = name
    this.id = id
}}
```

this is my typescript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from './models/Country';
import countries from '../assets/countries.json'; 

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 selection:Country = countries[0]
 allCountries:Country[] = <Country[]>countries

 constructor() {
 }

 onSelect(id:string) {
  let choice:number = +id[0]
  this.selection = this.allCountries[choice]
}
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<main class="content" role="main">
  <select #choice class="form-select" (change)="onSelect(choice.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let c of allCountries" [value]="c.id">{{c.name}}</option>
  </select>

  <h2>{{selection.labels}}</h2>
</main>
```

So `{{selection.name}}` is always empty and `{{selection}}` displays [object HTMLInputElement] on chrome. I don't understand why selection is not an object of Country.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
Was just the variable name 'selection' not good for angular...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).